# How can I get gnuradio oot blocks to work with extern defined variables and functions?

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I have created a OOT module for gnuradio based on someone elses code. For the process of generation the module I use gnuradios gr_modtools to add the blocks etc.

To make a variable (and function) globally available I used

```
gr_modtools add -t noblock -l cpp global_vars
```

within global_vars.h I define a function

```
extern STATE *state;
extern void initialize_reader_state();
```

Were STATE is a structure defined in the global_vars.h. The function does basically just create an instance of state and sets some values in the struct. In one of the other blocks I do make a call for that function.

Everything compiles fine when using the standart sequence (mkdir build && cd build && cmake ../ && make && sudo make install && sudo make ldconfig). At least there are no error messages or warnings.

But when I want to use the block that makes the call in gnuradio-companion I do get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'gate'
```

Where gr-foo (foo) is the OOT module and gate is a Block in this module. If I remove the function call and the extern variables/function it works (except for the function call of course).

I am at a loss here now. How do I get this to work so I dont get the attributeError? What do I need to adjust? Maybe the swig file needs adjustment, but I am not familiar with swig so would need some help here.

Thanks for any hints and help in advance.

Comment: hm, the error looks like you try to access `foo.gate` from Python, but in your C++ (honestly, this looks more like you're trying to write C than C++), `foo` is a function, not a type...

Comment: Hi, gnuradio uses swig to make functions etc accessible via python in the gnuradio-companion. The code itself is available as .cc source files with respective .h headerfiles. So swig does some 'magic' to make that happen. as long as I dont use the extern vars or functions everything works fine. i can for example reproduce the square_ff block from the howto tutorial on the gnuradio site.

Comment: I kinda know GNU Radio. But your error message says you're trying to access `foo.gate`, and your code says foo is a function. Something doesn't fit!

Comment: ah sorry, I named the function foo as example, but the module i use is gr_foo and gate is a block; the actual function I use is called initizalize_reader_state() not foo(). sorry for the confusion. I updated the post to avoid further confusions.

Comment: could you correct your question above, so that the confusion is mitigated for future readers, please :)